# Console UI in Winform App

Tags: winforms, command-line, user-interface

We have a legacy application running on UNIX. Our windows users login to the application via a terminal application or commaind prompt. The app looks like one of those car-dealer like application which runs in dos mode interface.

I am creating a new winform interface to the application but still want to keep the legacy application online for a while, however I dont want the users to open up command prompt, but instead access the application from within my winform. Is there a usercontrol which I can place on the winform for command prompt access?

> Solution ~ Ended up using a control from Rebex.net, fast integration and easy to use.

Comment: Adding links for the convenience: Rebex supplies terminal controls in two flawours: the Telnet component (http://www.rebex.net/telnet.net) and SSH Shell one (http://www.rebex.net/ssh-shell.net/). Both shares the same terminal emulator WinForms control.

Answer (score 2):

See this [blog post from Jeffrey](http://www.rootsilver.com/2007/08/how-to-create-a-consolewindow)
With his code you can write to a Console window, even from a Windows Forms application.

NOTE
I would NOT recommend to do that. 
A Windows Application should use the Windows as GUI and not the console window...

Comment: Blog post is down. Got here from Google search. I now have more questions than answers. :(

Answer (score 1):

I've been keeping my eye on this one.  It looks promising.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Terminal_Control_Project.aspx?fid=469468&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2857639