# Need Console-element in GUI App

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, console

My Question is short:

How can I add a Element that has the same function like a console, see output and aswell do input.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942397/console-ui-in-winform-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox) or a [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser) control.

if you need exactly a `console control` see this article in *code project* (this one uses `RichTextBox`):

- [Embedding a Console in a C# Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335909/Embedding-a-Console-in-a-C-Application)